# Problem with validatin settings "columns jumping around"

Tags: sharepoint-online, validation, column-validation

So I got my formula to work the way I want it to a point.

Here is my formula (I guess its kinda bad, but it kinda works out).

```
=IF(AND(Ärendetyp="LSP";Status="Tekniker klar");IF(AND([Ärende tilldelat]<>"";[Ärende påbörjat]<>"");TRUE;FALSE);TRUE)=IF(AND(Ärendetyp="MSP";Status="Tekniker klar");IF(AND([Ärende tilldelat]<>"";[Ärende påbörjat]<>"");TRUE;FALSE);TRUE)=IF(AND(Ärendetyp="HSP";Status="Tekniker klar");IF(AND([Ärende tilldelat]<>"";[Ärende påbörjat]<>"");TRUE;FALSE);TRUE)
```

But when I'm going to create a object in the list and I for example don't type in a value in "ärende påbörjat" it gives me the correct error, but now its starting to automatically open other column and I have to click several times on the correct column and after about 4 clicks I can fill in the missing value.

Sorry for my bad English, hope you guys understand anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the validation formula as below firstly:

```
=IF(AND(Ärendetyp="LSP",Status="Tekniker klar"),IF(AND([Ärende tilldelat]<>"",[Ärende påbörjat]<>""),TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)

=IF(AND(Ärendetyp="MSP",Status="Tekniker klar"),IF(AND([Ärende tilldelat]<>"",[Ärende påbörjat]<>""),TRUE;FALSE),TRUE)

=IF(AND(Ärendetyp="HSP",Status="Tekniker klar"),IF(AND([Ärende tilldelat]<>"",[Ärende påbörjat]<>""),TRUE;FALSE),TRUE)
```

Check if the issue exists. Based on my test, this formula works as expected.

If the issue still exists, try to create a new list and check again. Besides, you can provide screenshots about the issue.

Comment: Hello! This wont work for me, gets syntax error.. I have to use ";" instead of "," because other region

Comment: Its kinda hard to explain the issue.. So when I test this function it works as espected, it denies me to save the object because I have no value in either "Ärende tilldelat" or "ärende påbörjat". Men then when I try the click the column for example "Ärende inkommet" so type in the missing value its directing me to "Tekniker klar" column instead and I have to click the "ärende inkommet" column several times before I can type the value I want.

Comment: What's the type of your columns in this list?

Comment: [Ärendetyp] & [Tekniker klar] is alternative (Multible choiche column) and [Ärende tilldelat] & [ärende påbörjat] is just "Single row with text".

Comment: What's the relationship between "Status" and "Tekniker klar" column? What's the meaning of 'Status="Tekniker klar"' in your formula?

Comment: Its the status of the object, Tekniker klart=Techinician finished. Status is a multible choice column, and when you choose "tekniker klar" it will close the object, but I want it to confirm that IF I have choosed either LSP,MSP,HSP and I want to close the object, then "Ärende tilldelat" and "Ärende påbörjat" has to have value

Comment: Whether you set the validation  in list settings->validation settings? The multiple choice column is not supported to use in the formula.

Comment: Yes, its in settings>validation settings. Can I change the formula or something? Because I want the system to check if I have choosen either LSP,MSP or HSP and I try to close the object by choosing "tekniker klar" it will deny to close it if I havent filled in "ärende inkommet" and "ärende påbörjat" ?